# Fractional scaling causing blurriness, other issues in apps

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-graphics, wayland

I’m having issues w/ fractional scaling in Ubuntu 23.04. I also had these issues running on Ubuntu 22.04

Variants of this question have been asked before, like here: [Fractional scaling makes browser blurred](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415924/fractional-scaling-makes-browser-blurred)

Native apps seem to be mostly good, like gnome terminal, settings screens, etc. Chrome, Brave, Firefox, Slack, Steam are all blurry. Git Cola looks good with the exception of strangely large mouse cursors.

I’ve tried some of the options like enabling Wayland support in Chrome and Brave, and it actually made the browser window absurdly large and make it unusable so I had to revert the setting.

I also played around with some of the font and icon size changes, but it doesn’t really work for me since I’m in a dual-monitor setup with one monitor being 32” 4k, and the other being 15.6” 1080p.

Ideally, I’d have a 150% scale on the 1080p screen, and 200% scale on the 4k screen. I dual boot Windows 11 and these are the settings I have and it works great.

I’d love for an actual fix, but from the sounds of it, it seems like it’s just going to take time for apps to catch up and work well with Wayland.

But what I’m also wondering, is this perhaps graphics card / hardware dependent? Is anyone out there running a similar mixed size/resolution multi-monitor setup where this works well?

This is all on a Beelink SER5 mini PC w/ a Ryzen 5 5600H with AMD Radeon integrated graphics.

I’m looking at building a new PC, so I’d be open to picking up specific hardware if it’s guaranteed to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very new bug in Chrome that throws fractional scaling out of whack, but it just appeared a few days ago and is already fixed upstream. Hang on, I would expect the next Chrome update to fix fractional scaling when you have Wayland enabled in Chrome.

To revert to 'working but blurry' in the meantime, set "Preferred Ozone platform" to 'default' (not Auto). That will use the XWayland backend. Then after the next patch, flip it to 'auto' which will use Wayland with fractional scaling where it can & should.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the fix to the bug, they might actually be reverting the Wayland implementation of fractional scaling farther than I thought. the bug is here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1356014

Either way, the next update should be 'better' than now in any case re: this issue, and if they have to re-release proper fractional scaling, it's likely coming soon.

Comment: That's helpful. Thank you. It's not a total fix to all of the aforementioned problems, but it would definitely solve a problem in one of the most key apps in my day to day work. I'll give it another shot in the near future once that fix releases.